# Is there a way to get a list with variable names in Pyomo?

Tags: python, instance-variables, pyomo, environ

I wanna append all of my integer-bounded variables into the *integer_constraints_list* that i've defined. Is there a way to get some sort of list or array with all of my variable names to iterate over the code i made using a *for* loop?
something like `variables_list = [inst.x[i], inst.y[i], inst.z[i]]`.

I know there is something of the sort for pyomo kernel, but i used environ to define the model

```
model.I = RangeSet(1,20)
model.x = Var(model.I, domain=NonNegativeIntegers)
model.y = Var(model.I, domain=NonPositiveIntegers)
model.z = Var(model.I, domain=NonPositiveIntegers)

inst = model.create_instance(data)
integer_constraints_list = []

for i in inst.I:
     if "nonnegativeintegers" in str(inst.x[i].domain).lower():
          integer_constraints_list.append(inst.x[i])
          inst.x[i].domain = NonNegativeReals
```

to something like

```
variables_list = [inst.x[i], inst.y[i], inst.z[i]]
for v in variables_list:
     for i in inst.I:
          if "nonnegativeintegers" in str(v.domain).lower():
               integer_constraints_list.append(v[i])
               v.domain = NonNegativeReals
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest doing a domain equality comparison rather than a comparison on the string representation:

```
integer_vars = [v for v in inst.component_data_objects(Var) if v.domain == NonNegativeIntegers]
integer_constraints_list.extend(integer_vars)
for v in integer_vars:
    v.domain = NonNegativeReals
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
variables_list = ['inst.x', 'inst.y', 'inst.z']
for v in variables_list:
     for i in inst.I:
          if "nonnegativeintegers" in str(vars()[v][i].domain).lower():
               integer_constraints_list.append(v[i])
               vars()[v][i].domain = NonNegativeReals
```

Comment: didn't work :( it seems there are no keys with those names stored

Answer (score 0):

welp, the solution was not nearly as complex as i thought

```
variables_list = [inst.x, inst.y, inst.z]
for v in variables_list:
    for i in inst.I:
        if "nonnegativeintegers" in str(v[i].domain).lower():
           integer_constraints_list.append(v[i])
           v[i].domain = NonNegativeReals
```